# NodeJS get LDAP users in JSON

Tags: node.js, ldap, openldap

I would like to know if there’s way, using nodejs, to get all users from LDAP (openldap) in JSON format.

I’ve searched in npm library and GitHub, for some reason i didn’t find any similar.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Two components -- something like the http://ldapjs.org/client.html LDAP client to get the user information, then se JSON.stringify to build JSON-formatted output. In a real-world example, you'd want to use LDAPS or STARTTLS. Would probably also want to limit the attributes being returned (in the opts variable) instead of returning everything about every account. Depending on the size of the directory, you may also need to use a paged search. But this gives you a starting point:

```
var ldap = require('ldapjs');
var client = ldap.createClient({ url: 'ldap://directoryserver.example.com:389'});

client.bind('SystemID@example.com', 'Syst3m1DP@s5w0rd', function(err) {  assert.ifError(err);});

var iObjectsFound = 0;
console.log("[");

var opts = {  filter: '(&(samaccountname=*))',  scope: 'sub',  attributes: ['*']};

client.search('ou=ResourceUsers,dc=example,dc=com', opts, function(err, res) {
  assert.ifError(err);

  res.on('searchEntry', function(entry) {
    if(iObjectsFound > 0){  console.log(", ");  }
    iObjectsFound = iObjectsFound +1;
    console.log( JSON.stringify(entry.object) );
  });
  res.on('searchReference', function(referral) {
    console.log('referral: ' + referral.uris.join());
  });
  res.on('error', function(err) {
    console.error('error: ' + err.message);
  });
  res.on('end', function(result) {
    console.log('status: ' + result.status);
  });
});

console.log("]");
```